# Formatting Soap request in C# with a webRequest wrong encoding.

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm working with a third party that refuses to fix their scheme for a published WSDL.   The issue is the SOAP service is expecting different name spaces than the WSDL is providing.  So in my C# app I'm having a lot of trouble using the Proxy by .Net.  In an attempt to work around this I want to just send a web-request and package up my data.  I've been using Fiddler to compare my request to that generated by the proxy.

It appears that the proxy class is encoding the request I'm not sure how to get my C# webrequest to do the same thing.  Originally I thought they are gZipping it but that is not the case. At the end of the day I want to make my webRequest look just like a request coming from the Generated Proxy method that is created by visual studio.

In Fiddler the Proxy request looks like this:

[image]

My web-request looks like:
[image]

I'm not following how the generated c# code is encoding the message.

My C# code to send the SOAP request is as follows.

```
  public   void SendSoap(string messageHeader)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.Load(@"c:\temp\ReviewFilingRequest.xml");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(gz);
        }
        try {

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {                   
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


public HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://Illinois-stage.tylerhost.net/efm/FilingReviewMDEPort.svc");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction:\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServicesProfile-Definitions-4.0/FilingReviewMDEPort/ReviewFilingRequest\"");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");           
                webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");

                //  webRequest.Headers.Add("MIME - Version", "1.0");


                webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\";start=\"<http://tempuri.org/0>\";boundary=\"uuid:936f2c7e-590a-4f19-b154-ce8285adf18a+id=2\";start-info=\"text/xml\"";
                //webRequest.Accept = "gzip, deflate";

                webRequest.Method = "POST";

                webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(X509);
                return webRequest;
            }
```

Comment: I think I need to some how encode my message as SOAP 1.1 MTOM messages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up switching gears and used Node. Node has a lot of libraries to do the encoding.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=soap&page=1&ranking=optimal